# How to use strongly typed id in in EF?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have primitive obsession class `EmailAddress` that has overridden `ToString()`:

```
public class EmailAddress
{
   private string _value;

   public EmailAddress(string value)
   {
        _value = value;
   }

   public override string ToString()
   {
        return _value;
   }
}
```

My domain model `Customer` looks like:

```
public class Customer
{
   public EmailAddress EmailAddress { get; set; }
   public string FullName{ get; set; } 
}
```

And I have configured conversion for `EmailAddress` in FluentApi:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(x => x.EmailAddress)
                .HasConversion(
                x => x.ToString(),
                x => new EmailAddress(x));
```

Also I have generic repository pattern, and when I want to filter data:

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomers(GetCustomersQuery queryParameters)
{

  IQueryable<Customer> queryCustomers = _customerContext.GetAll();

  return queryCustomers.Where(x =>
         x.EmailAddress.ToString()
        .Contains(queryParameters.Email)).ToList();
}
```

I have got an error:

> The LINQ expression `DbSet<Customer>().Where(t => t.EmailAddress.ToString()` could not be translated. Additional
> information: Translation of method `object.ToString` failed.

I've tried EF 6.4 Do you have any workaround?

Comment: Why??  Just why overcomplicate your domain? You can internalize the setter and introduce a public method/class that sanitizes an e-mail. Keep the entity definition simple and functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For really motivated, who doesn't afraid of complicated domain, I have found solution

```
public class EmailAddress
{
   private string _value;

   public static explicit operator string(EmailAddress emailAddress) => emailAddress._value;

   public EmailAddress(string value)
   {
        _value = value;
   }

   public override string ToString()
   {
        return _value;
   }
}
```

and query is

```
queryCustomers.Where(x =>
         ((string)x.EmailAddress)
        .Contains(queryParameters.Email)).ToList();
```

this query is executing on server side.

Comment: Please post the SQL that your query generated, I’m curious.

Comment: Get rid of `class EmailAddress` and use a string directly, your problem will go away.

Comment: @Robert I would love to see what SQL was generated, still doubtful this is not client-side evaluation.